# First Posts Review audit passed without taking any action

Tags: bug, review, review-audits

This happened on this particular First Post review, I cannot reproduce it because review audits in "First Posts Reviews" don't come up very often:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/1776709

The post (an answer in this case) is clearly weak, this is a general agreement since it is a review audit. I was reading the question below the post being reviewed, and clicked the "See more comments" link in the bottom of the question. As soon as I clicked, I got the "Congratulations, this was an audit" message.

I was just checking the question, I hadn't taken any action on the answer that was to be reviewed yet. It seems like any action will trigger the audit response.

Comment: Since the original question only *has* 3 comments, I'd say the 'more comments' link is added just for the audit; you were paying attention and seeking more context; mission accomplished, you passed the audit! `status-bydesign`, in other words.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You are right, I noticed that the 'more comments' didn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is by design. What the process is supposed to weed out is robots that just click "accept" without looking farther.

OTOH, how to weed out the "deny" robots...